# How can I pass a URL of an OBJ file to G.Viewer using GET string syntax?

Tags: 3d, autodesk-viewer, wavefront

**The problem**

I have some OBJ and STL 3D model files accessible on the web.  My problem is making the files easy for my users to view online. I have tried to copy some pages that have such a web-viewer,  *but they ask the users to draw and drop local model files onto a box on a webpage.*

I want to pass the model URL as a get parameter.

I have not found a working web page that operates like this that I can blindly copy.

**Include details about your goal**

I would like to provide my users with a URL to a simple 3D web viewer, and pass the OBJ or STL file through a GET string parameter.  If my users click on that hot link they should see the 3D rendered OBJ or STL file.

**Describe expected and actual results**

I was expecting that I could create a web page that accepts a GET string variable called URL that would define the URL of the OBJ or STL file to be modeled.

I found a promising candidate at:

[http://masc.cs.gmu.edu/wiki/GViewer][1]

**Include any error messages**

This first iframe line on that web page, automatically loads the Beethoven.obj file in an iframe on a webpage, using the following single line of HTML code:

```
<iframe src="/objviewerframe.html?width=360&height=320&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmasc.cs.gmu.edu%2Fwiki%2Fuploads%2FObjViewer%2Fbeethoven.obj&dropable=true" width="380" height="340" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

I duplicated the line and changed the URL to point at one of my files.

```
<iframe src="/objviewerframe.html?width=360&height=320&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmasc.cs.gmu.edu%2Fwiki%2Fuploads%2FObjViewer%2Fbeethoven.obj&dropable=true" width="380" height="340" frameborder="0" ></iframe><br />
<hr />
<iframe src="/objviewerframe.html?width=1920&height=1020&url=http://cloud1.tri-di.com/data/uploaded/20210800003/20210812173402/photoscene-r0KcxuqPKFG3pnu2Ryj6ac4nFjsB0XpzRFbDVehJMN8/result.obj&dropable=true" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

However, what the 2nd iFrame does not show the URL I provided. It is asking for me to drag a file into the frame.

How can I get the 2nd iFrame to show the URL I provided?

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the tag `autodesk-viewer`:

If you wanted to use the [Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/) then you would need to create a site that would store the file on our server and get it translated to **SVF** (the format used by our web-based viewer)

This is the best tutorial for that:
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels